# wordpress menu link function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added the code below to my functions.php to add a "Login" Link to my wp menu.

```
 $newlink = '<li>' . $args->before . '<a title="Login" href="'. wp_login_url('index.php') .'">' . $args->link_before . 'Login' . $args->link_after . '</a>' . $args->after;
```

how can i change wp_login_url function to use another page? For example, I'm using the mingle plugin which creates a custom login page.

code below from wp-includes/general-template.php

```
 function wp_login_url($redirect = '', $force_reauth = false) {
        $login_url = site_url('wp-login.php', 'login');

        if ( !empty($redirect) )
                $login_url = add_query_arg('redirect_to', urlencode($redirect), $login_url);

        if ( $force_reauth )
                $login_url = add_query_arg('reauth', '1', $login_url);

        return apply_filters('login_url', $login_url, $redirect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend changing the core code of WordPress as you will likely break the install.

Can you not just update your functions.php file line of code to be something like:

```
 $newlink = '<li>' . $args->before . '<a title="Login" href="/login/">' . $args->link_before . 'Login' . $args->link_after . '</a>' . $args->after;
```